Springboot CRUD operation can not be edited
I created a CRUD project with Springboot. There is a relation table that is called order and it has relation with tables which are called Customer and Product. In my html page , there are labels for customer name and product name. When I edit an order and make a difference on product name or customer name , it is not changed on database. These are my files:
I tried findByName functions for customer and product but it did not work.
ordercontroller:
@GetMapping("/orders/edit/{id}")
    public String showEditOrderForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        try {
            Order order = orderService.getOrderById(id);
            model.addAttribute("order", order);

        } catch (OrderNotFoundException e) {
            ra.addFlashAttribute("message", "Product not found :(");
            return "redirect:/orders";
        }
        return "order/orderEdit";

    }

    @PostMapping("/orders/update/{id}")
    public String updateOrder(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute("order") Order order,Product product,Customer customer,Orderview orderview, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes ra) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "order/orderList";
        }

        try {
            String productName = orderview.getproductName();
            Customer existingCustomer=customerService.findByName1(order.getCustomerName());
            Product existingProduct=productService.findByName2(order.getProductName());
            Order existingOrder = orderService.getOrderById(id);
            orderService.updateOrder(id, order,product,customer );
            ra.addFlashAttribute("message", "The order has been updated successfully :)");

        } catch (OrderNotFoundException e) {
            return "redirect:/orders";
        }

        return "redirect:/orders";
    }

orderservice:
 @Override
    public Customer findCustomerByName(String customerName) throws CustomerNotFoundException {
        Optional<Customer> optionalCustomer = Optional.ofNullable(crepo.findByName(customerName));

        if (optionalCustomer.isEmpty()) {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer not found with name: " + customerName);
        }

        return optionalCustomer.get();
    }
    @Override
    public Product findProductByName(String productName) throws ProductNotFoundException {
        Optional<Product> optionalProduct = Optional.ofNullable(productRepository.findByName(productName));

        if (optionalProduct.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ProductNotFoundException("Product not found with name: " + productName);
        }

        return optionalProduct.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateOrder(Long id, Order updatedOrder, Product product, Customer customer) throws OrderNotFoundException {
        Optional<Order> optionalOrder = orderRepository.findById(id);
        Optional<Customer> optionalCustomer = crepo.findById(customer.getId());
        Optional<Product> optionalProduct = productRepository.findById(product.getId());

        if (optionalOrder.isPresent()) {
            Order existingOrder = optionalOrder.get();
            existingOrder.setDate(updatedOrder.getDate());
            existingOrder.setDeliveryStatus(updatedOrder.getDeliveryStatus());
            existingOrder.setCity(updatedOrder.getCity());


            System.out.println("Existing Order: " + existingOrder);
            System.out.println("Existing Customer: " + optionalCustomer.orElse(null));
            System.out.println("Existing Product: " + optionalProduct.orElse(null));



            if (optionalCustomer.isPresent() && optionalProduct.isPresent()) {
                existingOrder.setProduct(product);
                existingOrder.setCustomer(customer);
            } else {

                System.out.println("Customer or Product not found!");
            }

            orderRepository.save(existingOrder);
        } else {
            throw new OrderNotFoundException("Could not find any order with ID " + id);
        }
    }


order:
package com.example.demo.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Order1")
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;

    private String deliveryStatus;
    private String city;


    private String productName;
    private String customerName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    public Order() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    public Order(Date date, String deliveryStatus, String city) {
        this.date = date;
        this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDeliveryStatus() {
        return deliveryStatus;
    }

    public void setDeliveryStatus(String deliveryStatus) {
        this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}


orderview:
package com.example.demo.DTOs;

import com.example.demo.Model.Customer;
import com.example.demo.Model.Product;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Data
public class Orderview {
    private Long id;
    private String customerName;
    private String productName;
    private String city;
    private String deliveryStatus;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
    private Product product;
    private Customer customer;
    private Long productId;
    private Long customerId;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public String getDeliveryStatus() {
        return deliveryStatus;
    }

    public void setDeliveryStatus(String deliveryStatus) {
        this.deliveryStatus = deliveryStatus;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getproductName() {
        return productName;
    }


    public void setproductName(String pname) {
        this.productName = pname;
    }
    public String getCustomerName()
    {
        return customerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }


}



please paste the error logs which are appearing in console.
